# Display calendar month based off of the year and day the year starts (Java)

Tags: java, loops, input, calendar

I am writing a code that takes the user input year and month and prints out a calendar of the specific month based off of the given month. It uses loops to make the printout possible.

This is the desired output

```
Enter a year: 2013
Enter a month (1-12): 2

                 February 2013
    ----------------------------------------
    sun  mon  tue   wed  thrus   fri   sat
                                  1      2
    3     4    5    6     7       8      9
    10    11   12   13    14      15     16   
    17    18   19   20    21      22     23
    24    25   26   27    28
```

The thing with my code that I looked online on how to print an entire calendar (Jan to Dec full year) but I was wondering if there is a way to shorten the entire printout to just a selected month from the user. I did look at this question as a reference and found it quite helpful but the answers all print the entire year.
[How to display calendar in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679827/how-to-display-calendar-in-java)

What I believe should be changed about the program is that for the months there should be for loops and parts of the code determining if the year is a leap year or not. I think there should be an array for the selection of months and whichever one that is there will print out in the middle of the section.

Comment: There are many similar questions. If the one you’ve linked to doesn’t give you everything you need, just search for others. Only avoid answers that use `Calendar` or other date-time classes from Java 1.1 since they are poorly designed and long outdated. Use the answers that use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: What was your question, exactly, please?

Comment: If allowed use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this and tell me if it does what you are looking for:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
        int Y = sc.nextInt(); // year
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter the weekday the year starts on (1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, etc:) ");
        int startDayOfMonth = sc.nextInt();
        int spaces = startDayOfMonth-1;
        System.out.println();

        // startDayOfMonth

        // months[i] = name of month i
        String[] months = { "", // leave empty so that we start with months[1] = "January"
                "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
                "November", "December" };

        // days[i] = number of days in month i
        int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
        
        System.out.print("Enter the month you wish to display (1 for January, 2 for February, etc) ");
        int M = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        // check for leap year
        if ((((Y % 4 == 0) && (Y % 100 != 0)) || (Y % 400 == 0)) && M == 2)
            days[M] = 29;

        // print calendar header
        // Display the month and year
        System.out.println("          " + months[M] + " " + Y);

        // Display the lines
        System.out.println("_____________________________________");
        System.out.println("   Sun  Mon Tue   Wed Thu   Fri  Sat");

        // spaces required
        spaces = (days[M - 1] + spaces) % 7;

        // print the calendar
        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
            System.out.print("     ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= days[M]; i++) {
            System.out.printf(" %3d ", i);
            if (((i + spaces) % 7 == 0) || (i == days[M]))
                System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I edited the answer from the post you referenced to utilize a scanner that chooses a specific month rather than going through all of the months